# Generating two APKs from the same app

Tags: android, android-module

Trying to generate two APK files that can be installed separately on the same device, the only difference in the functionalities being the app icon.

My first assumption was to create two separate projects, but this didn't allow separate installation. So my question is: What parameters does Android use to distinguish apps? Is there a better practice when doing something like this?

Answer (score 3):

> What parameters does Android use to distinguish apps?

The `applicationId`, typically as set in the app module's `build.gradle` file.

> Is there a better practice when doing something like this?

Use [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors) to set up separate `applicationId` values and provide alternative launcher icons.